# Does the M1 chip (Apple Silicon) use hyper-threading? (a.k.a. simultaneous multithreading (SMT))

Tags: apple-silicon

With regard to the [Apple M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) chip, I have looked around at various sites but have not seen any mention of the [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) feature more commonly know by Intel’s trademark, [*Hyper-Threading Technology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading).

I suppose one could presume there is no SMT in the M1, but I would prefer seeing a definitive statement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no mention of SMT in Apple's documentation for M1. The closest we can get to definitive is what macOS tells us.

- On a Mac with an Intel chip supporting Hyper-Threading Technology, *Activity Monitor → Window → CPU Usage* shows twice the number of vertical bars as *System Information → Hardware → Total Number of Cores* reports.
- On a Mac with an M1 chip, the number of bars is the same as the number of reported cores.

Therefore we can conclude there is no hyper-threading.

[image: screenshot of System Information → Hardware → Total Number of Cores and Activity Monitor's Window → CPU Usage window.]

Comment: @Basil Bourque, Okay I'd obscure the Serial Number and UUIDs, but why obscure System Firmware Version and OS Loader Version?

Comment: @user3439894 Why not?

Comment: @grg Do you know which of the 8 bars are for the 'performance' and 'efficiency' cores?

Comment: @Gilby `powermetrics -s cpu_power` shows the first 4 as efficiency and the last 4 as performance, so I imagine this translates to Activity Monitor too.

Comment: @grg: I guess it makes sense to do it that way, because it allows to easily "turn the performance cores on and off" by simply reporting `numCpus = 4` or `8`, without having to make too many changes to the scheduling code of the OS. Heck, if the thermal management of the firmware does that automatically, you could even run an OS that doesn't even know about the different kinds of cores, and you would still get at least some of the benefits, as long as the OS supports CPU hot plugging.

Comment: On an Intel mac with Ventura, the _System Information_ window also explicitly mentions "Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled". I suppose that will be "Disabled" on M1/M2 macs.